# cannot log on to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: password

I have just finished loading on Ubuntu 14.03 now after putting in my password the screen goes blank then goes back to the password logon page

Comment: Is this a fresh install?

Answer (score 0):

Do Ctrl + Alt + F1 to go to prompt.Login with your username and password.Then do

sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/[username]

Then do  Ctrl + Alt + F7 to login

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work  its still taking me back to the logon screen